# Find sepecific text in multiple word document files

Tags: php, file

I want to build a search module in which user enter a text and that text should search all files in particular directory. I have used this code :

```
$path_to_check = 'E:/xampp/htdocs/talent_orbit/test/';
$needle = 'test';

foreach(glob($path_to_check.'*.txt') as $filename)
{
   //print_r(file($filename));
  foreach(file($filename) as $fli=>$fl)
  {
      echo $f1;
    if(strpos($fl, $needle)!==false)
    {
      echo $filename.' on line '.($fli+1).': '.$fl;
    }
  }
}
```

But it works only for .txt file, it should search in .doc file. I have also change `glob($path_to_check.'*.txt') as $filename)` to `glob($path_to_check.'*.doc') as $filename)` but it does not show the result. Please help me in this.

**EDIT :**

I also tried ont the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352153/search-for-phrase-word-in-text-files-with-php)

```
php > exec("egrep -rl 'string of what I want to find' full-or-relative-directory", $output);
php > print_r($output);
Array
(
  [0] => full-or-relative-directory/foo/bar.xml
)
php > $contents = file_get_contents($output[0]);
```

It shows Array(),I dont know what to put between "full-or-relative-directory" I mean the path.

My code :-

```
php > exec("egrep -rl 'rakesh' E:/xampp/htdocs/talent_orbit/test/", $output);
php > print_r($output);
```

**If it is not possible then can I convert doc file into txt file and then search in that txt file ?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: changing to .doc what error do you get ?

Comment: nothing.. it shows blank

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. A doc file isn't a '[plain text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_text)' file. Try opening it in your editor and you will see. Searching through `*.txt` and `*.xml` files will work, because those are basically all plaintext files. A doc file has binary data in it.

A solution would be a doc-parser for PHP (for example [this one](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)), but it will require a script that loops through the files, open each and every file with the parser and search for the string.

Comment: thanks for your reply so can I convert doc file to txt file and then search in that txt file ?

Comment: I guess that is possible. You can save your document in Word as `txt` I suppose. But you will lose all of the format and styling that way.

Comment: that will be ok for me can you tell me how to convert doc file to txt file ?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php) for more information on reading DOC-files with PHP. This way, if you get the contents, you can save them to a txt file and search it the way you want.